# Get attributes Name and Value of element in C# through System.Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have one custom config file.

```
<Students>
 <student>
   <Detail Name="abc" Class="1st Year">
       <add key="Main" value="web"/>
       <add key="Optional" value="database"/>
   </Detail>
 </student>
</Students>
```

I read this file through the IConfigurationHandler interface implementation. 
When I read the childNode attributes of Detail element. It return me below result into Immediate Window of IDE.

```
elem.Attributes.ToObjectArray()

{object[2]}
    [0]: {Attribute, Name="key", Value="Main"}
    [1]: {Attribute, Name="value", Value="web"}
```

When I try to write on Console

```
 Console.WriteLine("Value '{0}'",elem.Attributes.ToObjectArray());
```

it does return me

```
Value : 'System.Configuration.ConfigXmlAttribute'
```

`elem.Attributes.Item(1)` method gives me the Name and Value detail but here I need to pass the index value of attribute which I don't know currently.

I want to get Name and value of attribute through **LINQ query** and individual display on Console for each childNode attribute as follows:

```
Value : Name="Key" and Value="Main"
        Name="value", Value="web"
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do here? Fix the Console.Writeline?  Can you post more of your code so we can understand the flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use this [Xml Library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/) you can get all the students and their details with this code:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // or .Parse(string)
var students = root.Elements("student").Select(s => new
{
    Name = s.Get("Detail/Name", string.Empty),
    Class = s.Get("Detail/Class", string.Empty),
    Items = s.GetElements("Detail/add").Select(add => new
    {
        Key = add.Get("key", string.Empty),
        Value = add.Get("value", string.Empty)
    }).ToArray()
}).ToArray();
```

Then to iterate over them use:

```
foreach(var student in students)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", student.Name, student.Class));
    foreach(var item in student.Items)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("  Key: {0}, Value: {1}", item.Key, item.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Linq *Select* and *string.Join* to get the output you want.

```
string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    elem.Attributes.ToObjectArray()
        .Select(a => "Name=" + a.Name + ", Value=" + a.Value)
)
```

Comment: `String.Format()` would be a better choice: `.Select(a => string.format("Name={0}, Value={1}",a.Name,a.Value))`

Comment: elem.Attributes.ToObjectArray() .Select(a => "Name=" + a.Name + ", Value=" + a.Value);
not give the a.Name and a.Value here. I already try this but it's not return a.Name and a.Value.

Answer (score 2):

This will get all the attributes of the children of the Detail element as you state in your question.

```
XDocument x = XDocument.Parse("<Students> <student> <Detail Name=\"abc\" Class=\"1st Year\"> <add key=\"Main\" value=\"web\"/> <add key=\"Optional\" value=\"database\"/> </Detail> </student> </Students>");

var attributes = x.Descendants("Detail")
                  .Elements()
                  .Attributes()
                  .Select(d => new { Name = d.Name, Value = d.Value }).ToArray();

foreach (var attribute in attributes)
{
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name={0}, Value={1}", attribute.Name, attribute.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **Attributes** in an `object[]` as you wrote, which can be mocked by

```
var Attributes = new object[]{
    new {Name="key", Value="Main"},
    new {Name="value", Value="web"}
};
```

then the issue is that you have **anonymous types** whose names can't be extracted easily.

Take a look at this code (you can paste it into the main() method of a LinqPad editor window to execute it):

```
var linq=from a in Attributes
let s = string.Join(",",a).TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}').Split(',')
select new 
{
    Value = s[0].Split('=')[1].Trim(),
    Name = s[1].Split('=')[1].Trim()
};
//linq.Dump();
```

Since you cannot access the Name and Value properties of the variable **Attributes** inside the **object[]** array because the compiler hides them from you you, the trick is here to use the **Join(",", a)** method to get around this limitation.

All you need to do afterwards is to **trim** and **split** the resulting string and finally create a new object with **Value** and **Name** properties.
You can try it out if you uncomment the **linq.Dump();** line in LinqPad - it returns what you want and it is furthermore queryable by Linq statements.